# Google Script to delete all content in a Google Doc after a certain keyword

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Doc where I want to remove everything (including tables and horizontal lines) after a certain keyword, including the keyword itself. However, the script I have now isn't working correctly and I have no clue why. It's only removing a few paragraphs and not everything. Any insight?

```js
function deleteContent() {
  var keyword = "%delete%";
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var found = false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < body.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var element = body.getChild(i);
    if (element.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH && element.asParagraph().getText() == keyword) {
      found = true;
      for (var j = i+1; j < body.getNumChildren(); j++) {
        body.getChild(j).removeFromParent();
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to delete all contents after a paragraph of `%delete%` in Google Documents.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the child is deleted with the ascending order. In this case, the child index is confused. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When this script is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function deleteContent() {
  var keyword = "%delete%";
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var numChildren = body.getNumChildren();
  for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
    var element = body.getChild(i);
    if (element.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH && element.asParagraph().getText() == keyword) {
      for (var j = numChildren - 2; j >= i; j--) { // Modified
        body.getChild(j).removeFromParent();
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

- By the way, in the current stage, the last paragraph cannot be deleted using the Document service (DocumentApp). [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/01/17/deleting-last-empty-page-of-google-document-using-google-apps-script/) Please be careful about this. By this, I used `var j = body.getNumChildren() - 2` as the initial condition.
- About `How would you include also deleting the keyword?`, I modified the above script. `j >= i + 1` was modified to `j >= i`.

#### Reference:

- [removeFromParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#removefromparent)

Comment: This works great! Thank you. How would you include also deleting the keyword?

Comment: @Craig Thank you for replying. About `How would you include also deleting the keyword?`, I modified my answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the necessary changes to make it work.

```html
function deleteContent() {
  var keyword = "%delete%";
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var found = false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < body.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var element = body.getChild(i);
    if (element.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH && element.asParagraph().getText() === keyword) {
      found = true;
      for (var j = body.getNumChildren() - 1; j > i; j--) {
        body.getChild(j).removeFromParent();
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (found) {
   body.getChild(i).removeFromParent();
  }
}
```